# Can I move my Playstation profile from hard disk to USB?

Tags: psn, ps4

Is it possible to move your Playstation profile (which resides on the consoles hard drive), to a USB? I am not talking about save games, but the actual account itself.

I know that I can download it from the Playstation store, but my problem is that this requires the user to enter the password every time.  This becomes quite cumbersome if you're using a long complex password.

I guess what I am thinking of is a feature similar to the Xbox 360, where you can put your profile on a USB and then all you need to do is insert the USB to log in to your account on a different console.

Comment: You can set it to sign in automatically after the first time

Comment: @BenBrocka assuming he is attempting to login to a playstation he doesn't own, this wouldn't be desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not. I know sony only allows certain things to be transfered to and from USB drives. Profiles on playstations do not roam like on Xbox, they cannot be used on more than 2 different consoles currently with ps3 and pretty sure same goes with ps4. This is just so you have a backup system or if you live in 2 homes and do not want to bring your system everywhere you go. This also limits the effects of gamesharing.